# Webscraping an hidden url?

Tags: web, web-scraping

I am trying to find an effective way to detect hidden urls on a website.

Currently, im trying to web scrape a website with the following URL [www.somewebsite.com/folders/XXXXX](http://www.somewebsite.com/folders/XXXXX) the XXXXX is a number between 1000-20000, the simplest way would be to run a loop that replaces the XXXXX with a number and then checks if the webpage exits, not all numbers lead to a folder, however I am unsure if this will cause a website overload. I am wondering if there is an easier way to see what folders actually exist, I am doing this as a user and there is no xml sitemap nor an index from which I can navigate, I simply know that some numbers lead to a valid folder.

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer this question.  It depends on the site.  There may be a directory listing, or there may be a sitemap, or there may be links to the valid URLs.  It is impossible to know without more details from you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the library `grequests` to send tons of requests
and a for loop. Example:

```
import grequests

for x in range(1000,200001):
    req = grequests.get(f"www.somewebsite.com/folders/{x}")
    # Code ...
```

Hope I could help :)